# PHP Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given in

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, wordpress

I have gone through all of the other posts on here that I can find regarding this warning, but I cannot seem to correct it. Warning is `PHP Warning:  in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given in...`.

The code:

```
$my_teachers = $student->my_teachers;
                
if (in_array($teacher_email, $my_teachers)) {
```

I understand that $my_teachers needs to be an array, but it is as far as I can tell. The value is created by creating an array, pushing the teacher's emails into the array, and saving it to MySQL. The MySQL database row shows as

```
a:2:{i:1;s:16:"teacheremail1@gmail.com";i:2;s:18:"teacheremail2@gmail.com";}
```

Is this actually storing as a String and I'm not realizing it? Either way, how do I get rid of the warning? The code still gives me the intended results, but the warning is filling up my error_log.

Comment: Seems it's a `serialize()` string. Use `unserialize($string)` to transform back into array.

Comment: Usually the frameworks have an built-in way to transform back to array/object. You may need to look at your project (wordpress or plugin) to see if there is a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you could add an extra check, like:

```
$my_teachers = gettype($student->my_teachers) === 'array' ? $student->my_teachers : unserialize($student->my_teachers);
```